# My android application cannot play again when clicking button

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I'm new in android programming. My first application is an android mediaplayer.

I built two buttons : one to play a song, and another to stop it.

My application is running correctly ; the problem is that i can play and stop it, **but I cant play the song again.**

I tried to use `setDataSource()` but it triggers an error.

Here's the code ; the file is in `raw/song.mp3`

```
    package com.example.test6;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     final Button btnPlay = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button btnStop = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
                mp.start();

        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {       
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.stop();
                }else{

        mp.setDataSource("res/raw/song.mp3");
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();                    
        }               
    }); 
   }    
}
```

Comment: hi, and welcome to SO. I edited your question to make it more readable. It is advised to use short sentences and proper formatting : it is more simple for people to understand your problem and to answer it.

Comment: Thank you Mr..actually i'm new in SO and not familiar about the formatting..i joined this for studying because i'm still a student..i hope everyone can help me..thank you again.

Comment: joining SO for studies is a good move, in fact that's how i learned a LOT of what i know now. If you feel like it, try to help people on simple questions, you will learn quite a bit in the process because the questions here reflect real-life problems, and because it forces you to clear your mind in order to explain the solutions. Again, welcome :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to set the data source manually if you're doing the creation like this: `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);` Also, in that case, you don't need to call `prepare()` because `MediaPlayer.create()` does that for you.

I would suggest this kind of approach (assuming you don't want the start button to do anything if it's already playing):

Start button listener:

```
if (mp==null) {
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
}
if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
     mp.start();
}
```

Stop button listener:

```
if (mp!=null) {
     if (mp.isPlaying()) {
          mp.stop();
     }
     mp.release();
     mp = null;
}
```

I didn't test this, so I'm looking forward to your response

Comment: i have try to put `mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);` but it trigger an error at `create`.

Comment: Which line is causing the exception, and what kind of exception? Maybe if you provide some more info, people can help you better

Comment: thank you so much for helping me..but i still encounter an error at `create`.i already try another solution but still dont work..so frustrated..=(

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. Post your LogCat results. If you're not using LogCat yet, google it. Try the Media Playback developer guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html, and check the MediaPlayer reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: thank you..i will try to post the LogCat ..sorry because i'm new in android programming..

Comment: Hi Mr Revolutionair..i already done doing my MediaPlayer application..i used your code and add my `MainActivity` into it..thank you so much for helping me..now i want to try making the application more interesting..thank you again..=)

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer has been helpful, you could upvote it (the upwards triangle). Also, if it was correct, you can mark it as the answer to your question (check icon)